# How to use regression in python-weka-wrapper?

Tags: python, regression, wrapper, weka

I would like to implement regression algorithms using python-weka-wrapper in Jupyter Notebook. However, I couldn't find the correct function in https://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper/api.html#classifiers

Does someone know how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

In the olden days, Weka distinguished between classification and regression algorithms, but that got dropped in favor of just a single super class.

The *capabilities* of a `weka.classifiers.Classifier` determine what types of attributes and class attributes an algorithm can handle. Some algorithms, like `RandomForest` can do both, classification and regression.

All regression algorithms implemented the `Classifier` interface, so just pick a regression algorithm, like `LinearRegression` or `M5P`, and use the same Python wrapper which you would use for classification.

The example code that you referenced uses the `classify_instance` method which you would use for regression schemes to get the numeric prediction. In case of classification algorithms, this method returns the index of the predicted class label.

**BTW** The Python 2.7-based `python-weka-wrapper` library is no longer maintained and you should use `python-weka-wrapper3` instead. Here is the same link, but for pww3:

https://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/api.html#classifiers